# Can we create a full dynamic web-site using just CMS like Joomla,Drupal,etc..?or should know some programming like php,jsp beforehand?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Should one need to learn php(or jsp) to create dynamic web-sites or just to use CMS ?.I am new to web-development...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use the CMS without understanding how it works then you are limited by what the CMS will do out of the box or with plugins. You will have little scope for customisation, and not be  able to fix things if anything breaks.

It really depends what you want to achieve. **If** a CMS does everything you need it to do, then you can probably get away with just using it out of the box.

(And now I will resist the urge to start a language war and just say that there are other languages beyond PHP and Java).

Comment: Yea,i am currently developing sites using jsp & js.Now trying to check out php...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use cms without knowledge about php, css or even html.

Comment: As long as you don't want to chance the internal workings of your website & everything keeps running as it should. (read: not going to happen)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do in what scope. If you're looking to set up a web site for your band (for example), there's no need to learn PHP. There are plenty of CMSes that can be set up without deep PHP knowledge.

If you want to start a web development career, however, learning a server-side language is pretty mandatory.

Comment: thx for the answer.So if i want to add/update a new logic or functionality into my web-site(something like an advanced encryption),then can i code into the existing CMS modules??

Answer (score 0):

CMS Made Simple does not require much technical knowledge. Some is benefecient. But in the old days I used to work with complete lack of php/js.